# extracting "tag" information from git with a shell script

Tags: bash, awk, git

The [vc bundle](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/vc/git-unix/) is a neat little package that extracts information about a git repo for easy insertion into a LaTeX document. It doesn't currently extract information about whether the current commit is tagged and what the tag name is. How would I edit the `vc` script to do this?

And then how would I edit the `vc-git.awk` script to add an extra line to the generated vc.tex file? Presumably I want a line that looks like:

```
print "\\gdef\\GITTag{" Tag "}%"
```

but I need an earlier line that tells awk what `" Tag "` means?

This isn't a question about LaTeX, it is about git, awk and bash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git log --decorate -1 [commit]
```

If `commit` (`HEAD` if omitted) has tags, the commit hash will be followed by `(tag: name)` (and possibly multiple other symbolic references too).  You can pick this out more specifically with

```
git log --pretty=%d
```

Comment: This i great, I've added `Tag: %d` to the `vc` script linked to above, and copied a line in the `awk` script that extracts the information to a TeX macro. This gives me a macro that does: `(HEAD, tag: v1.01, master)` I just need to cut this down to the `v1.01` part only...

Comment: `/^GITTag:/ {print $4}'` prints `v1.01,` Now I just need to delete that comma!

Comment: `print substr($4,1,length($4)-1)` works

Answer (score 1):

You can get what commit tag points to by:

```
git show -s 'TAG_NAME^{commit}' --format='%H'
```

Unfortunatly I'm afraid that the only way of checking if commit is tagged it to check all tags.

Comment: That's the opposite of what I want: I want to know how to know what tag is attached to a given commit...

Comment: I don't think the reverse is possible in other way then going through all tags and checking what commits they point to.

Answer (score 1):

You can get from a commit to a tag name by using `name-rev`.

```
git name-rev <commit> --tags
```

An example:

```
$ git name-rev fcfeabe --tags
fcfeabe tags/v2.36-beta2
```

So to get only the tag:

```
git name-rev fcfeabe --tags | awk '{sub("tags/", ""); print $2}'
```